# Meteor - Server-side API call and insert into mongodb every minute

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, settimeout

I am in the process of learning Meteor while at the same time experimenting with the TwitchTV API.

My goal right now is to call the TwitchAPI every minute and then insert part of the json object into the mongo database. Since MongoDB matches on `_id` and Twitch uses `_id` as its key I am hoping subsequent inserts will either update existing records or create a new one if the `_id` doesnt exist yet.

The call and insert (at least the initial one) seem to be working fine. However, I can't seem to get the `Meteor.setTimeout()` function to work. The call happens when I start the app but does not continue occurring every minute.

Here is what I have in a `.js`. file in my server folder:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getStreams: function() {
        this.unblock();
        var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=3';
        return Meteor.http.get(url);
    },
    saveStreams: function() {
        Meteor.call('getStreams', function(err, res) {
            var data = res.data;

            Test.insert(data);
        }
    }
});

Deps.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){Meteor.call('saveStreams');}, 1000);
});
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to be using [Meteor.setInterval](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_setinterval) rather than Meteor.setTimeout for this use case.

Comment: Deps.autorun is not supposed to be used server-side, use Meteor.startup instead.

Comment: @richsilv this solved my problem. Not sure how I missed that function. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the changes mentioned by @richsilv and @saimeunt and it worked. Resulting code:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){Meteor.call('saveStreams');}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That will execute your call every secound since the functions take millisecounds as parameter.
setTimeout(function, ms) and setInterval(function, ms)